# Issues with displaying data using Next/React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Issues:
What I'm trying to do is to display various sets of data on my page. There are few rules that I'm using/doing to do that; however, some datas aren't showing.

Rule No. 1:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/evaluations/search-by-id/${localStorage.getItem("1317")}`).then(res => res.json()).then(evaluationDetailsExtractedData => {
            setEvaluationData(evaluationDetailsExtractedData)
});
```

I was able to get the data using the above code. Followed by the Rule No. 2where in I'll be getting the (Template) for the said Evaluation.

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/evaluations/search-by-id/${localStorage.getItem("1317")}`).then(res => res.json()).then(evaluationDetailsExtractedData => {
            setEvaluationData(evaluationDetailsExtractedData)
            // console.log(evaluationDetailsExtractedData)

            fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/options/get-all-option-by-title`, {
                method : 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${AccessToken}`
                    },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: evaluationDetailsExtractedData.template
                })
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions => {
                setEvaluationOptions(searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions)
                console.log(searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions)
            })
        });
```

On the above Rule, I was successfully displayed the data/information needed. However, when mapping the Rule No. 3, that's where I'm getting the issues. What's the purpose of Rule No. 2: It will allow me to get the certain subTitle from another database which, will serve as the Title of the content. For example:

Rule No. 1: I will get the template used for the evaluation which is: Chatter-001 (Database: Evaluations)
Rule No. 2: I will get all the subTitle associated with the said Template (Database: Options)
Rule No. 3: I want to display the content of the said subTitle based on the information stored (Database: Evaluation Data)

Here's the below NextJS Code for the frontend so you can picturized the targeted design.

```
{
                        evaluationOptions.map((evalOptData) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <b className="px-1 text-light bg-danger">{evalOptData.subTitle}</b> (Rule No. 2)
                                    <Card.Body>
                                        <Row className="px-5">
                                            Rule No. 3
                                        </Row>
                                    </Card.Body>
                                </>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

Here's the final code where I'm getting the issues:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/evaluations/search-by-id/${localStorage.getItem("1317")}`).then(res => res.json()).then(evaluationDetailsExtractedData => {
            setEvaluationData(evaluationDetailsExtractedData)
            // console.log(evaluationDetailsExtractedData)

            fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/options/get-all-option-by-title`, {
                method : 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${AccessToken}`
                    },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    title: evaluationDetailsExtractedData.template
                })
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions => {
                setEvaluationOptions(searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions)
                console.log(searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions)

                searchForOptionUsingTitleEvaluationOptions.map((displayAllData) => {
                    console.log(displayAllData)
                    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/api/evaluations-data/search-by-id-and-title`, {
                        method : 'POST',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                'Authorization': `Bearer ${AccessToken}`
                            },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            evaluationId: localStorage.getItem("1317"),
                            title: displayAllData.subTitle
                        })
                    }).then(res => res.json()).then(generateAllEvaluationsByUser => {
                        setEvaluationResults(generateAllEvaluationsByUser)
                        console.log(generateAllEvaluationsByUser)
                    })
                })
            })
        });
```

Comment: Please specify what issue you are facing exactly? Its not clear from your code. Are you getting some errors, or empty data, or what?

Comment: I am getting an empty data. On my console, the information displays as multiple number of array which are the exact information I need but when applying them doesnt show any data. They appeared as blank. This link might help: https://ibb.co/WWJK2Kn

Comment: Yeah, by the look of the code, it seems the issue is related to your API calls inside .map() function.

Comment: It seems, yes. I've been stock here for a while now. Hahahaha. Can't figure it out. I also tried to map them and display on div id but I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: I can imagine. I am looking into your code, however just a tip, try converting your fetch calls into async/await format. It would make it much cleaner and clear, and will help in debugging the issue. Something like this:
const evaluationsResponse = await fetch(
    `http://localhost:4000/api/evaluations/search-by-id/${localStorage.getItem(
      "1317"
    )}`
  );

  const evaluationDetailsExtractedData = await evaluationsResponse.json();

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Still waiting for the answer.